# Populate text field initial value based on input from other text field

Tags: java, install4j

I'm working on an installer that will deploy a package to a remote machine. For this I have to ask the user for the username of the remote machine.

I'd also like to have the user specify the path to which the file gets copied. For this I have another text field on the same configurable form page.

Is there any way to have the destination field auto-complete based on the input in the username field above it?

For example, say the user types `user1` in the username field, I'd like the destination field to populate to `/home/user1/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the "Input validation expression" property of the user name text field to

```
if (!text.equals(context.getVariable("lastValue"))) {
    ((JTextField)formEnvironment.getFormComponentById("2060")
       .getConfigurationObject()).setText(text);
    context.setVariable("lastValue", text);
} 
return true;
```

where "123" is replaced by the ID of the destination text field. After the field uses focus, the destination field is updated.

The installer variable "lastValue" holds the previous value of the user name text field so that the destination text field is only changed if the value has changed.

**Alternatively:** To update the text field as you type, set the "Key listener script" property of the user name text field to the above script minus the return statement.

This property will be available starting with install4j 6.0.4.

Comment: Did some more testing and looks like a side-effect of this is that, despite the user changing the destination field, the value of the variable assigned to that field remains the same as one set via the Input Validation Expression on the user name field.

Is there any workaround so that I can have a default set using the input validation but still allow the user to manually modify the destination field with whatever path he wants?

Comment: You're right, the input verification is also performed when the user clicks "Next". I've updated my answer with a solution.

Comment: @IngoKegel I've tried the solution and it works. However, I'm getting unwanted behavior. The value of the field being **updated** seems to be one character behind. I know this is the default behavior of KeyDown event, but I'm hoping whatever value is entered is reflected in the other textbox below it. Do you have any solutions? Right know I am doing two validation expressions, one for Key validation and another for Input validation. The end user might get confused.

Comment: @Chris You're right, for the "Key validation expression" it lags by one character. I've edited my answer with a script for that property.

Comment: @IngoKegel The only problem I can see from this is that if a user makes a correction in the middle of the form, then the reflected form would not be accurate. So let's say I modified `install4j` and put a 5 in the middle to show `insta5ll4j`, the reflected box would instead show `install4j5`

Comment: @Chris Right, this will never work like that for deletions since the user could have selected a range, and only the insertion index is reported. I've added a "Key listener script" property for 6.0.4 where the "text" parameter already contains the modified text. If you would like a pre-release build of that version, contact support@ej-technologies.com.

Comment: @IngoKegel Thank you! I would love to try it out.